# VSCodium terminal error message => error layer=debugger can't find build-id note on binary?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have VSCodium v1.64.2 and have this error message in my integrated terminal window upon "Run/Start Debugging" command:

2022-02-14T17:14:16-06:00 error layer=debugger can't find build-id note on binary

This error message appears on all my programs inside the terminal window. I'm learning Golang (GO) and am new to the VSCodium (VSCode community) editor. My program runs fine with no errors in my Ubuntu terminal window as well as the integrated terminal in VSCodium.

Is there something I can do to correct the error? It's not interfering with my work, but I was curious. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [issue](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/2900) of go-delve / delve (
@latestas delve@1.8.2of 2022/02/13), this problem is not addressed, so
install delve manually instead of installing with VS Code extension etc

```
# Install at tree head:
$ go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@master
```

or

```
$ git clone https://github.com/go-delve/delve
$ cd delve
$ go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/go-delve/delve/pull/2893, which has been merged, it should now just be a warning. You likely pulled delve before the merge, though, so updating should fix this.